# Table of contents cut off at the bottom of the page

Tags: table-of-contents, overleaf

I have the next problem, but I can't find the error
[image]

The code I am using is the next:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl} %para las celdas en color
\usepackage{lscape} % pagina apaisada
\usepackage{comment} % comentar algo
\usepackage{qrcode}  %para hacer codigos qr
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}




\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}


%%%%%%% Margenes
%\setpapersize{A4}
\usepackage[left=1.7cm,top=1.8cm,right=1.7cm,bottom=1.8cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}


%%%%%%% INTERLINEADO
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
%\onehalfspace

%%  Para cabecera y pie de pagina
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{xxxxxx}
\lhead{xxxxxx}
\cfoot{\thepage}


%%% Para poner comentarios
\newcommand{\com}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{**#1 **}}}
\newcommand{\res}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{**#1 **}}}
\newcommand{\tgr}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{green}{**#1 **}}}


\begin{document}

\begingroup
\begin{titlepage}
    \newgeometry{left=0cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm, right=0cm}
    \AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,0){\includegraphics[scale=1]{portada.pdf}}} % pdf de fondo de portada
    \noindent
    \vspace{125mm}
\end{titlepage}
\endgroup

\tableofcontents
%\clearpage

%\let\clearpage\relax
\include{Texto/1-xxxx.tex}
\include{Texto/2-xxxxx.tex}
\include{Texto/3-xxxx.tex} % 
\include{Texto/4-xxxx.tex}
\include{Texto/5-xxxxx.tex}
\include{Texto/6-xxxx.tex}
\include{Texto/7-xxxxxx.tex}
\include{Texto/8-xxxxxx.tex}
\include{Texto/8.5-xxxx.tex}
\include{Texto/9-xxxxxxx.tex}
\include{Texto/10-xxxxxx.tex}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Texto/referencias.bib}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide a complete document that shows this?

Comment: Updated question. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately the shown code is not complete and even if we replace `protada.pdf`, e.g., by `example-image` it does not show the problem. Please see “[I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964)” for more information.

Comment: What problem? The output you show looks reasonable to me.

Comment: Do you think that the table of contents must be limited to one page?  Perhaps there might be some tens of entries; how do you suggest these should be displayed?

Comment: It is not cut off at the bottom of the page, it is continued onto the next page.

Comment: Table of contents should continue to section 10. And in 8, there are more subsections.  I have tried to remove the \begingroup, dedicated to the cover, and the table of contents appears correctly.  but I don't know where the error can be here